# API - Direct url to the right controller

Tags: php, apache, api, rest

I'm currently writing a RESTful API for my service.
My url scheme is this:
www.mydomain.com/api/user - POST method, create new user
www.mydomain.com/api/user/id - GET/PUT method- Fetch/update user's details

I wrote the userController.php on the server that handles those request and returns the right response. It's on my server in the /api/userController.php

My question is how do I direct the above url's (http://www.mydomain.com/api/user/ and http://www.mydomain.com/api/user/id) to activate the userController.php on the server?
Do I do it through the .htaccess file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file, replace this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ userController.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that every url call like www.mydomain.com/api/user will trigger the /api/userController.php?

Comment: Yes -- if it's in `/api/.htaccess`, and your apache is configured to honor `.htaccess` files.

Comment: What if I have several resources and I want to direct them to the right controller? For example, if I have a /api/book resource how do I direct it to /api/bookController

Comment: I recommend having an `api router` that is routed to via .htaccess, then using that router to call to the appropriate controller, based on the path it receives (i.e. what URL was called).

Comment: You mean like having a main controller that will be triggered with every api call and it will trigger that right resource controller according to the url. Correct?

Comment: That's correct -- this way, you won't have to modify `.htaccess` ever again once the project gets rolling :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much. Check out [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). I hope you're wearing your RegEx hat.